# Iphone Custom Navigation Bar - White Box Error

Tags: objective-c, ios4, uinavigationbar

My problem is simple. I used the method of subclassing navigation bar, and then using drawRect to attempt to draw my own custom navigation bar image. However, it doesn't draw my image... only a blank white space.

The structure of my project is a tab bar with a navigation controller under each one of it's tabs. Each navigation controller has a navigation bar and I have set those bars to my custom class (customNavBar) in IB.

In my customNavBar.h file I have:

```
@interface customNavBar : UINavigationBar {
}

@end
```

In my customNavBar.m file I have:

```
#import "customNavBar.h"


@implementation customNavBar

-(void) dealloc{
    [super dealloc];
}


- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"navigation_bg.png"];
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(55, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
}

@end
```

Any ideas why my image might not be showing and instead just getting a white background? My image is in the project under the resources folder.

Thank you everyone. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I implemented your code in a test project, I did in fact see the image. I however did

```
[image drawInRect:self.frame];
```

The image ended up covering the bottom half of the nav bar and the top half was white (like you are seeing). Perhaps your image is being drawn too low? Try playing with the rect values or just set it to self.frame like I did and see what happens. If you still don't see image, make sure your nav bar class is actual set to your custom class in interface builder and that code is being called to draw your nav bar (maybe put print statement be sure).

Comment: Self.frame doesn't change anything... i also verified that I am getting into my draw method. Hmm :(

Comment: omg... spelling error... navigation_bg is incorrect... the images actual name is navigaton_bg

Comment: Arghhhhhhhhhdfdfdf sorry for wasting time but perhaps someone will see this white box problem and see the simple error!

Comment: Errors like that always happen to me! Then you spend hours trying to figure out whats wrong and in the end...haha

Comment: Absolutely Nitrex... i spent 2 hours on that. Navigation and navigaton look almost exactly the same. >.<

Answer (score 0):

it actually should be:

```
[image drawInRect:self.bounds];
```

and don't forget `navigation_bg@2x.png` for Reitna-dislays